# React: pull dependent data from custom hooks into component without re-rendering when non-dependent data changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If a component uses some data from a custom hook and if the custom hook also contains data (local/global) which is not consumed by the above component, then the component re-renders even when the non-dependent data changes (references for non-primitive types). Is there a way to prevent this?

Example code:

useTest.hook.js

```
export default function useTest() {
  const {
    consumedData, nonConsumedData
  } = useSelector(state => state.Data);

  return {
    consumedData,
    nonConsumedData
  }
}
```

Component.js

```
export default function Component() {
    const {consumedData} = useTest();
    return <div>{consumedData}</div>;
}
```

Here Component re-renders when nonConsumedData changes ( or even when state.Data changes ). nonConsumedData might be consumed by some other component. Is there a way to stop the re-render in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use memoization to avoid re-rendering components (if re-rendering affects performances).

With function based components, just use `React.memo()`

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
});
```

More information here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Is there any other way other than memoizing? This is a pretty much direct thing where I want to re-render only when my subscribed data changes, something like a useSelector for redux which does it out of the box.

Comment: You can also use a specific hook with only your consumedData